# Any idea how to interpret these pseudocode colons?

Tags: pseudocode

This is my first post. So, please be gentle.

My professor has given me this pseudocode to follow but I dont know how to interpret the colons and `od;`.

I've aded an image of what he's given us but also have the pseudocode typed below

[image: Image of pseudocode]

```
read12Bits() : 12Bit =
  declare Result : 12Bit = 0; 
  for i = 1 to 12
    do
      declare lBit : Bit = input() // get next bit 
      if ( lBit == 1 )
       then Result = (1 << (i-1)) + Result; //set bit at index i
    od;
  return Result;
```

Comment: Those things after colons are types. The first after `read12Bits` must be the return type of the func. `od;` is the end indicator for the block started with `do;`. It's like conditionals (`if`/`fi`) or loops in bash. Pseudocode is really just less clear Python and confuses me all the time. Welcome to SO, BTW!

Answer (score 1):

If I were to interpret it:

- `read12Bits() : 12Bit` : read12Bits is a method that returns 12Bit
- `declare Result : 12Bit = 0` : Result is a variable of 12Bit type. Result is set to a value of 0
- `do` `od` is a pair. The do block starts with `do` and ends in `od`, similar to `if`, `fi` in shell scripting

I wonder if that's Algol 68 syntax: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_loop#1968:_Algol_68

Comment: @captainnello You're welcome. Feel free to Upvote/Accept the answer. :)